# Magento 2 Canonical url for home cms page

Tags: magento2, seo, canonical

As per SEO expert I need to have domain url as canonicalurl. As per magento 2 settings doesnt allow it to be empty. attached screenshot shows same. I get https://www.portablerestroomtrailers.com/homepage. It should be https://www.portablerestroomtrailers.com/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create app/design/frontend///Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

And Add this into it

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" src="https://www.yourdomain.com" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: there is no folder Magento_CMS. should i create one?

Comment: No need. Just create cms_index_index.xml in any layout folder